# How to get attributes values from nested xml node?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have XElement object formated like this :

```
<Setting guid="3bcedf55-b75f-456b-b90a-a92cbbb022ga">
    <PatientFieldList>
        <PatientFieldSetting PatientName="UserDecision" PatentFieldLength="64" />
        <PatientFieldSetting PatientName="prohibited" PatentFieldLength="128" />
    </PatientFieldList>
</Setting>
```

I have to get values of all attributes in all nodes but I don't know how :/ I tried

```
xml.Elements("PatientFieldList")

xml.Descendants("PatientsSettingsFieldsList").Where(x => x.Attribute("PatentFieldLength").Value == 64)`
```

I have a lot of node like that so i wonder if there is easy way to access to these attribute by '[]' or somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq

var xml = "<Setting ...";
var doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
int i; // for int parse
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("PatientFieldSetting")
        let name = node.Attribute("PatientName")
        let length = node.Attribute("PatentFieldLength")
        select new { Name = (name != null) ? name.Value : "", Length = (length != null && Int32.TryParse(length.Value, out i)) ? i : 0 };

foreach (var node in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, Length={1}", node.Name, node.Length);
}
```

Output:

```
Name=UserDecision, Length=64
Name=prohibited, Length=128
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print out attributes of all nodes which have attributes in your xml:

```
XDocument doc = //your data

var q = from node in doc.Descendants()
        where node.Attributes().Count() > 0
        select new {NodeName = node.Name, Attributes = node.Attributes()};

foreach (var node in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine( node.NodeName );
    foreach (var attribute in node.Attributes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(attribute.Name + ":" + attribute.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

If you only want PatientFieldSetting nodes filter for the name:

```
from node in doc.Descendants("PatientFieldSetting")
```